# PL/SQL output a string and a number with execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm pretty new to PL/SQL and I'm trying to figure out which columns aren't use for which type in my table.
That'ts mean I have something like :

```
 ____________________     ...    ________
|   A  |  B  |  C   |     ...      Type  |
|______|_____|______|     ...    ________|
|(null)| val | val  |     ...       1    |
|(null)| val | val  |   2 JOINS     1    |
|  val | val |(null)|     ...       2    |
|  val | val |(null)|     ...       2    |
|  .   |  .  |   .  |     ...       3    |
|  .   |  .  |   .  |     ...       .    |
|______|_____|______|     ...    ________|
```

I want outputs like this :

```
  for Type 1 : cols used are B, C
  for Type 2 : cols used are A, B
  ... OR
  Col A is used by type 1
  Col B is used by type 1, 2
  Col C is used by type 2
```

- "Used" means that there's at least 1 result not null in the column
- We get Type from 2 INNER JOINS

I was doing it col by col like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(A), Type
FROM enregistrement
INNER JOIN 1
ON idA = idB
INNER JOIN TYPES
ON id1 = id2
WHERE A IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Type;
```

Note the result where count > 0 and then change the `A` by `B` and so on ...

Then I heard about PL/SQL ! ... And trying thing like this :

```
declare 
  mytable varchar(32) := 'ENREGISTREMENT';
  cursor s1 (mytable varchar2) is 
            select column_name 
            from user_tab_columns
            where table_name = mytable
            and nullable = 'Y';
  mycolumn varchar2(32);
  query varchar2(100);    
  mycount number;
  type varchar2(10);
begin

  open s1 (mytable);
  loop
     fetch s1 into mycolumn; 
         exit when s1%NOTFOUND;

     query := 'select count('||mycolumn||') FROM ' || mytable 
              || ' INNER JOIN 1 ON idA = idB ' 
              || ' INNER JOIN Type ON id1 = id2 '
              || ' where '  || mycolumn || ' is not null GROUP BY type';

     execute immediate query USING mycount, ficlbl ;

     dbms_output.put_line('Col' || mycolumn || ' is used by ' || type || ' :  ' || mycount );

  end loop;
end;
```

Which throw an ORA-06502 :(

I'm not even sur this is possible with `execute immediate` ...

Comment: It helps to show the full error stack. An obvious problem is that your dynamic SQL has 'from' twice: `) from FROM ' || mytable `. What will look for a table *called* `FROM` and give it an *alias* taken from your `mytable` variable. But there may be others issues too...

Comment: Well the DB structure is more complex than id1= id2 for the join ... I simplified it ;) And the `from from` is an typo error here ... not in my code :)

Comment: So you want us to spot syntax errors in code you're butchering before you paste it here? How do you think we're going to be able to that? Also, `ORA-06502` is a generic PL/SQL exception. You should post the entire error stack.

Comment: Simplifying or modifying your code to post your question is fine, but only if it's still valid - seems like you're introducing distracting errors while posting. [An MCVE would be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And again, show your whole error stack, not just the not-very-helpful ORA-06502.

Comment: I'm not searching for syntax correctors ... Thanks ...  It's more to help me  in a general case ... I don't want to copy past a code from Stack .. I want to understand and to achieve the command on my own ... And my error log is in french so it won't help you ... :/

Comment: I could have delete the last part where I'm trying to do PL/SQL and just ask for "How to do so inPL/SQL ?"  ... But then you would have answer "Put some code, Try on your own, etc ..." ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an odd requirement. However, it can be done purely in SQL using conditional aggregated COUNT, like so:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT NULL a, 10 b, 100 c, 1 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT NULL a, 20 b, 120 c, 1 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 20 a, 30 b, NULL c, 2 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 40 a, 40 b, NULL c, 2 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 80 a, NULL b, NULL c, 3 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT NULL a, NULL b, NULL c, 4 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 30 a, 10 b, NULL c, 5 TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 60 a, 10 b, 3 c, 5 TYPE FROM dual)
-- end of subquery mimicking data in your table. See SQL below:
SELECT TYPE,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(a) > 0 THEN 'Y' END a_col_used,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(b) > 0 THEN 'Y' END b_col_used,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 0 THEN 'Y' END c_col_used
FROM   sample_data
GROUP BY TYPE
ORDER BY TYPE;

      TYPE A_COL_USED B_COL_USED C_COL_USED
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1            Y          Y
         2 Y          Y          
         3 Y                     
         4                       
         5 Y          Y          Y
```

If you have to, you could output the results as a concatenated string (something like `select 'for type '||type||' columns used are '|| case when count(a) > 0 then 'A, ' end|| ...` - you might have to use rtrim to trim off any dangling `,`s though:

Comment: That's clearly odd but for an odd requirement it does the work... But it makes me write a lot of copy/past that's why I tried to do it programatically with PL/SQL ... Nevermin I'll do it like that                    PS : it's an odd question but it's in order to change the structure of the BDD and make it easier

Comment: So this is just a one-off task? If so, and if you don't want to manually type all the case expressions out, you could query user_tab_columns and select the text, e.g. `select 'case when count('||column_name||') > 0 then ''Y'' end,' from user_tab_columns where...`

Comment: exactly what I wanted haha thx (even if yes it was an one-off task and already done ;) ) :)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is hard because compilation errors become runtime errors. So start with a SQL statement that executes properly, then edit to make it dynamic.

This is not valid SQL; it wouldn't run as SQL so it won't in PL/SQL either:

```
|| ' INNER JOIN 1 idA = idB '
```

You need to learn how to look at your code with a fiercer eye.